# How to iterate through categorical variables in r

Tags: r, categorical-data

I fitted a logistic regression model on `titanic` dataset, which consists of several categorical variables.

```
surv.glm= glm(survived ~ class + age + sex, data=titanic, family=binomial)


Coefficients:
   (Intercept)  class2nd class  class3rd class       ageadults          sexman  
         3.062          -1.011          -1.766          -1.056          -2.369
```

part of data:

```
class       age     sex survived
1st class   adults  man yes
1st class   adults  man yes
```

There are three classes (1st, 2nd and 3th) in data. There is a `crew` level in the filed of `class` but it seems it doesn't appear in data. so, two zero for 2nd and 3th classes must indicate 1st class.

The question is:

> Find the probability of survival for all possible cases in the titanic incident. Sort them by the probability of survival. Automate the process as much as you can.

Based on the coefficients of model I wrote this code:

```
predict_surv = function(class_2nd, class_3th, age_adult,sex_man) {
  surv=3.062-1.011*class_2nd-1.766*class_3th-1.056*age_adult-2.369*sex_man 
  odd = exp(surv)
  p = odd / (1 + odd)
  return(p)
}

i <- 1
for (class2nd in c(0,1))
  for (class3th in c(0,1))
    for (adult in c(0,1))
      for (sex in c(0,1)) {
        pr[[i]] = predict_surv(class2nd,class3th,adult,sex)
        i <- i+1
      }
pr = sort(pr,decreasing = T)
print(pr)
```

It works, but I would like to print the actual label for each combination of categorical variables in the output. How can I do that in a efficient and standard solution with R?

Comment: Read up on what `Intercept` represents in a linear model.

Comment: you can use `predict.glm` along with `expand.grid` to create new data with all possible combinations. Please add necessary packages in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed like this:

Some data:

```
library(titanic)
titanic_comp <- titanic_train[complete.cases(titanic_train),]
```

create a model:

```
model <- glm(Survived ~ Pclass + Age + Sex,
             data = titanic_comp,
             family = binomial)
```

create all possible combinations

```
new.data <- expand.grid(Pclass = unique(titanic_train$Pclass),
                        Age = unique(titanic_train$Age),
                        Sex = unique(titanic_train$Sex))
```

predict all possible combinations

```
new.data$prob <- predict(model, new.data, "response")
```

sort

```
new.data[order(new.data$prob, decreasing = TRUE),]

head(new.data[order(new.data$prob, decreasing = TRUE),])
    Pclass  Age    Sex      prob
521      1 0.42 female 0.9770664
515      1 0.67 female 0.9768586
494      1 0.75 female 0.9767917
377      1 0.83 female 0.9767247
473      1 0.92 female 0.9766490
437      1 1.00 female 0.9765815
```

So, if you were a wealthy baby girl you could have easily survived the titanic.